# How to wait for an NMI interrupt without polling?

Tags: bash, interrupt, polling, nmi

To wait for an NMI interrupt, currently I do:

```
while true; do

  RES=$(cat /proc/interrupts | grep NMI)
  RES=$(echo "$RES" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
  RES=$(echo "$RES" | sed 's/^0*//')

  if [ "$RES" != "" ]; then

    echo "DONE"
    exit 0
  
  fi

  sleep 1

done
```

Is there a nicer way to do this without polling or sleeping?

Comment: Cross-posted, @Maestro, delete one. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743062/how-to-wait-for-an-interrupt-without-polling

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: If you are parsing a file (such as `/proc/interrupts`) you could at least show a representative sample of its contents! Also, it seems a bit much to use 4 processes (`cat`, `grep`, 2x `sed`) when a single `awk` could do all that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just parse the count number for the NMI interrupt there and check if its non-zero, but I guessed it was not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for an NMI interrupt without polling can be achieved by using an event-driven approach. Instead of constantly checking the /proc/interrupts file, you can use a signal handler to catch the NMI signal and execute the required actions when the signal is received.
Sad but, you cannot directly catch an NMI interrupt in a user-space script, as NMI interrupts are reserved for kernel-level code. However, you can write a kernel module to handle NMI interrupts and pass a signal to your user-space script when an NMI occurs.

Here is what you can do..
First: Write a kernel module to handle NMI interrupts. then when an NMI occurs, let the kernel module send a signal (e.g., SIGUSR1) to your user-space script. At last in your script, set up a signal handler to catch the signal sent by the kernel module and execute the required action. And check example below:

```
handle_signal() {
echo "NMI interrupt received"
echo "DONE"
exit 0
}

trap 'handle_signal' SIGUSR1
start_nmi_module
while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Answering the comment:

hmm, if you are unable to modify the kernel or add modules to the machines, then yes, your current method is likely the best option. But, you can make a few optimizations to reduce the load because of polling:

Example using awk:

```
while true; do
  RES=$(awk '/NMI/ {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {sum+=$i}} END {print sum}' /proc/interrupts)

  if [ "$RES" != "" ] && [ "$RES" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "DONE"
    exit 0
  fi

  sleep 5
done
```

This script uses awk to read the `/proc/interrupts` file and sum the NMI interrupt counts for all the CPU. If the total count is not zero, the script exits with "DONE". The sleep interval has been increased to 5 seconds, because it will reduce the frequency and system load.

Answering second question:

So sad but, without kernel modifications or access to kernel modules, your options for handling NMI interrupts in real-time are limited.
But, you can try to strike a balance between delay and load by changing the sleep interval according. Example, use a smaller sleep interval such as 0.1 or something like that or maybe 0.5 seconds. This would decrease the delay handling, the interrupt while not excessively increasing the system load.

```
while true; do


RES=$(awk '/NMI/ {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {sum+=$i}} END {print sum}' /proc/interrupts)

  if [ "$RES" != "" ] && [ "$RES" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "DONE"
    exit 0
  fi

  sleep 0.1
done
```

Remember that this is still a polling and there will always be a trade between response time and load. Choosing carefully the sleep interval you can find the balance for your specific case.

Comment: I am not able to make any modifications to the kernel of the machines this script runs once. So I guess that means my current method is the only way?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The whole reason I wanted to get rid of sleep is to decrease the delay in handling the interrupt. So increasing it to 5 has the opposite effect. And decreasing it too much will waste cycles.

Comment: @Maestro check again, hopefully this answers your question, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid solution: As the kernel will log NMIs, too, redirect kernel messages to a separate file (or FIFO) via `syslogd`, and then grep for the NMI event in that file:

If there is no output, your process will block; only if there is some output, the grep will do something. Make sure the lines are not buffered before output to the file or FIFO.